# selenium webdriver click javascript link

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium

I am using Selenium-webdriver with C# to test a website. I have a issue that when I use `Click()` to click a link, it doesn't work. It should open a new window when clicked. I tool a look in the html structure, I found there is a Javascript action on the link.

The html as following:

```
<span class="new_doc">
  <a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:popwinnewproject('pc.aspx?page=docnew2tree&j=P2&grp=actv&t=');">
    <img title="new doc" src="http://local:8080/res/icon/new-doc.png"/>
```

What method should I use to click it to open the new window?

Comment: In JavaScript the `OnClick` event is used to do some action when a button, link etc... are clicked. So it will definitely connected with a element. Post some more HTML code.

Comment: How are you identifying this link?

Comment: More HTML code had been add

Comment: var button = BrowserDriver.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='barbutton']//img[@title='" + btn + "']/.."));
button.Click();

Answer (score 0):

I use in some cases click with JavaScript:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor).driver;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", myElement);
```

Where, myElement is a *IWebElement*.